# CSS Rendering Plane

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a simple example which can be viewed here:

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ee8c25;
  transition: transform 1000ms linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.plane:first-child {
  /*transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
}

.plane:last-child {
  /*transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
  background: #d14730;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="plane">First Plane</div>
  <div class="plane">Second Plane</div>
</div>
```

The code in question is this one

```
.plane:first-child {
  /*transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
}

.plane:last-child {
/*   transform: rotateY(180deg); */
  background: #d14730;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

It contains two elements which are absolutely positioned and they take whole space of their parent. The reason second plane is displayed above the first one is because it comes after in the source code and I get that.

The thing I dont get is, why when the second .plane element is rotated by 180deg, it is not longer in front of the previous element, it goes to the 'back'. But if the first .plane is rotated and the second is not, first is still in front, it doesnt go back like the second element does.

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `transform-style: preserve-3d;` it finishes on the same plane. Which make sense I guess because it's transitioning in front of the first `.plane`.

I'm not sure if you can transform whilst preserving the 3d space and get it to finish above the first `.plane`. Because if elements are rotating 180 degrees on the Y axis, and rendering in a 3D space, then that means they will aways be behind everything. The element will be styled exactly the same as it would appear from the front, but reversed on the back. The Z axis essentially, like a mirror.

[image]

See your code below (with `transform-style: preserve-3d;` removed) and see gif above showing the result when activating your `transform: rotateY(180deg)` css via the console.

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tomato;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*transform-style: preserve-3d;*/
  perspective: 700px;
}

.plane {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ee8c25;
  transition: transform 1000ms linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.plane:first-child {
  /*transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
}

.plane:last-child {
  /*transform: rotateY(180deg);*/
  background: #d14730;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="plane">First Plane</div>
  <div class="plane">Second Plane</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: yes without the 3d option it's logical because this is the painting order ... Also I don't see how this answer the question? Am pretty sure the 3D is needed and we need to know why such behavior with it. Also this behavior is not the same cross browser, so it would intresting to know the good one and why

Comment: ah i see what you mean give two mins to check

Comment: See this is what i thought the preserve-3d behaviour was, see this https://imgur.com/a/ezgth3d for his example. I thought preserve-3d essential was a z axis. Which if that is the case then this answers his question.

Comment: When both are rotated it's intuitive and I also think like this ... but try to rotate only one at a time and within different browser (Chrome and FF), you will see different behavior ... this is the strange part and it's there where we cannot have a clear conclusion about the behavior since it behave differently

Comment: I was talking about rotating them individually, as they are siblings they're using the same parent preserve-3d style. Though you are absolutely right, in web-kit browsers you get the logical result, but in Firefox it's like it ignores the preserve-3d style on the final render. Very odd, well spotted!